# How to display jgrowl messages on page redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jgrowl

I have setup jgrowl and everything seems to working correctly. I currently have to press a button to trigger the message to appear in the top right side of the screen like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$.jGrowl('Your transaction has been processed', { life: 10000 });" href="javascript:void(0);" value="Default"/>
```

What i want is for the jgrowl message to now pop-up automatically when i redirect in my controller:

```
def ch_sum_total
    #....some processing stuff code....
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the message you want to Growl into you action on the controller so you can see if you have to show the jGrowl.

So something like this:

```
def ch_sum_total
    #....some processing stuff code....

    flash[:notice] = 'Your transaction has been processed'

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

and on the `:back` page you have something like:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
      $.jGrowl('<%= escape_javascript(flash.discard(:notice)) %>', { life: 10000});
    <% end %>
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is definitely the more "railsy" approach.

Comment: @Manuel thanks that worked perfectly +1, i think i will learn jquery, because the features are just awesome, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler by passing `$(...)` a function.

```
$(function() {
  $.jGrowl('Your transaction has been processed', { life: 10000});
});
```

This will prevent your code from executing until the DOM is loaded and jGrowl can be properly displayed.

Comment: thanks, however the message pops up on every page, and i just need jgrowl to pop up after a redirect in rails. Sorry about the noob question i am still learning jquery. Can you explain a bit more. thanks again for your help.